# Magento checkout stuck with "Submitting Order Information"

Tags: magento, checkout

Magento checkout process stuck at the last step (on click of Place Order button) with the progress dialog box "Submitting Order Information" & user doesn't get to the thank you page.  Although on the back-end order is placed successfully.

Magento Enterprise Version 1.13.

Thank you,
DJ

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Magento log files (`[magento root]/var/log/exception.log` and `system.log`)?  Have you recently installed any extensions / tried uninstalling them?  If you have Magento Enterprise, you are paying a boatload for support, have you contacted them?  Have you researched this at all?  What have you found?  This likely belongs in the Magento Stack Exchange if on any Stack Exchange

Comment: Most likely something is producing an exception during checkout and you have error reporting turned off, so you don't see the exception.

Comment: if you are using chrome, may be you shall see the output of XHR requests, and see what is coming up in there

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to make a clear diagnosis, but I would venture to say that one of your extensions is not handling or failing to let the process complete. As a result the line of code where the redirect to the order success page is never reached.

A quick way to confirm this would be to disable all extensions by setting  to true and trying to complete an order. This setting can be found in the **/app/etc/local.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in my Magento instance.

But in my case I was facing because, All products in my Magento website were **downloadable** and downloadable product doesn't have any **shipping method**. There was a custom module, which was trying to fetch shipping method from order, after order placing. That's why it was giving error before getting success page.